# Floating carousel elements wrap instead of remaining all on the same row and don't show up when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, animation, overflow, carousel

I have almost 20 `<div>` with pictures in a slider but only 6 are showing up:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var view = $("#tslshow");
  var move = "196px";
  var sliderLimit = -450

  $("#rightArrow").click(function() {
    var currentPosition = parseInt(view.css("left"));
    
    if (currentPosition >= sliderLimit) view.stop(false, true).animate({
      left: "-=" + move
    }, {
      duration: 200
    })
  });

  $("#leftArrow").click(function() {
    var currentPosition = parseInt(view.css("left"));
    
    if (currentPosition < 0) view.stop(false, true).animate({
      left: "+=" + move
    }, {
      duration: 200
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.bstimeslider {
  background: transparent;
  height: 126px;
  position: relative;  
  width: 1100px;  
}

.bktibx { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block; 
  height: 126px; 
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  width: 186px; 
}

.bktibx-top { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block; 
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 166px; 
}

.bktibx img { 
  height: 88px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 186px;
}

#tslshow {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;  
}

#leftArrow {
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#rightArrow { 
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#viewContainer {
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1020px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bstimeslider">

  <div id="rightArrow"></div>
  
  <div id="viewContainer">
    <div id="tslshow">
    
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bktibx">
        <div class="bktibx-top">
          transparent
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="leftArrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: To understand why the rest do not show up, remove `overflow:hidden` from `#viewContainer`. And, please, read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are wrapping because `#tslshow` is not wide enough, as you can see if you check with the inspector.

You have 3 options to fix it:

1. Use [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) (with some additional adjustments you can see in the snippet below):

   ```
   .bktibx {
       display: inline-block; /* Instead of float: left */
   }

   #tslshow {
       white-space: nowrap;
       font-size: 0;
   }
   ```
2. Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

   ```
   .bktibx {
       /* Just remove float: left; */
   }

   #tslshow {
       display: flex;
   }
   ```
3. Use `max-width: unset` and [`min-width: max-content` (experimental)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width):

   ```
   #tslshow {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       max-width: unset;
       min-width: max-content;
   }
   ```

With the first and second options, you can also remove the `position: absolute` from `#tslshow` and use `transform: translate(-Npx)` and `transition: translate ease-in 250ms` to scroll it and animate it.

In the third one, you can still use `left`, but animate it with `transition: left ease-in 250ms` instead of using jQuery.

#### Option 1 - white-space: nowrap:

```js
const scrollable = document.getElementById('tslshow');
const children = 20;

// Just to avoid having that big ching of HTML:
scrollable.innerHTML = `
  <div class="bktibx">
    <div class="bktibx-top">Title</div>
    <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
  </div>
`.repeat(children);

const move = 196;
const min = - (move * scrollable.children.length) + 10 + scrollable.offsetWidth;

let current = 0;

document.getElementById('rightArrow').onclick = () => {
  current = Math.max(min, current - move);

  scrollable.style.transform = `translate(${ current }px)`;
};

document.getElementById('leftArrow').onclick = () => {
  current = Math.min(0, current + move);

  scrollable.style.transform = `translate(${ current }px)`;
};
```

```css
.bstimeslider {
  background: transparent;
  height: 126px;
  position: relative;  
  width: 100%;  
}

.bktibx { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block; 
  height: 126px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  width: 186px;
  
  /* I have changed this (instead of float: left)... */
  display: inline-block;
}

.bktibx-top { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 166px;
  
  /* ...removed the float: left here... */
}

.bktibx img { 
  height: 88px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 186px;
}

#tslshow {
  /* ...changed this completelly... */
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform ease-in 250ms;
}

#leftArrow {
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#rightArrow { 
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#viewContainer {
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* ...and changed this. */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bstimeslider">
  <div id="rightArrow"></div>
  
  <div id="viewContainer">
    <div id="tslshow"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="leftArrow"></div>
</div>
```

#### ✨ Option 2 - Flexbox:

```js
const scrollable = document.getElementById('tslshow');
const children = 20;

// Just to avoid having that big ching of HTML:
scrollable.innerHTML = `
  <div class="bktibx">
    <div class="bktibx-top">Title</div>
    <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
  </div>
`.repeat(children);

const move = 196;
const min = - (move * scrollable.children.length) + 10 + scrollable.offsetWidth;

let current = 0;

document.getElementById('rightArrow').onclick = () => {
  current = Math.max(min, current - move);

  scrollable.style.transform = `translate(${ current }px)`;
};

document.getElementById('leftArrow').onclick = () => {
  current = Math.min(0, current + move);

  scrollable.style.transform = `translate(${ current }px)`;
};
```

```css
.bstimeslider {
  background: transparent;
  height: 126px;
  position: relative;  
  width: 100%;  
}

.bktibx { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block; 
  height: 126px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  width: 186px; 

  /* I have removed float: left here... */
}

.bktibx-top { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 166px; 
}

.bktibx img { 
  height: 88px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 186px;
}

#tslshow {
  /* ...changed this completelly... */
  display: flex;
  transition: transform ease-in 250ms;
}

#leftArrow {
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#rightArrow { 
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#viewContainer {
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* ...changed this. */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bstimeslider">
  <div id="rightArrow"></div>
  
  <div id="viewContainer">
    <div id="tslshow"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="leftArrow"></div>
</div>
```

#### Option 3 - Experimental max-width: max-content

```js
const scrollable = document.getElementById('tslshow');
const children = 20;

// Just to avoid having that big ching of HTML:
scrollable.innerHTML = `
  <div class="bktibx">
    <div class="bktibx-top">Title</div>
    <img src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OPN.RTNews_iokoUEg279vnqHFa5nIABQ&w=186&h=88&c=7&rs=2&qlt=80&cdv=1&pid=News"/>
  </div>
`.repeat(children);

const move = 196;
const min = - (move * scrollable.children.length) + 10 + scrollable.parentElement.offsetWidth;

let current = 0;

document.getElementById('rightArrow').onclick = () => {
  current = Math.max(min, current - move);

  scrollable.style.left = `${ current }px`;
};

document.getElementById('leftArrow').onclick = () => {
  current = Math.min(0, current + move);

  scrollable.style.left = `${ current }px`;
};
```

```css
.bstimeslider {
  background: transparent;
  height: 126px;
  position: relative;  
  width: 100%;  
}

.bktibx { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block; 
  height: 126px; 
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  width: 186px; 
}

.bktibx-top { 
  background: rgba(17,17,17,.7);
  color: #ffffff; 
  display: block; 
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 166px; 
}

.bktibx img { 
  height: 88px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 186px;
}

#tslshow {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  
  /* I have change this... */
  max-width: unset;
  min-width: max-content;
  transition: left ease-in 250ms;
}

#leftArrow {
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#rightArrow { 
  background: #ff0000; 
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 41px;
  width: 40px;
}

#viewContainer {
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* ...and this */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bstimeslider">
  <div id="rightArrow"></div>
  
  <div id="viewContainer">
    <div id="tslshow"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="leftArrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first one still does not show them all. The second one messed the whole thing unless I added it wrong. Thanks

Comment: Take a look to the edit, you can see it's working there.

Comment: It works great. How can i make the main div smaller 1100px it is the full width of the page. Thanks

Comment: Just change the `width` of `.bstimeslider` or wrap it with another element with the desired width.